# Sorting bibliography entries of similar author and year

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sorting

The problem: some authors publish in books they edited:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@incollection{majorbookch1,
  author  ={The Good},
  title   ={Chapter One},
  pages   ={1--10},
  crossref={majorbook}}

@book{majorbook,
  editor  ={The Good},
  title   ={Some Nice Title},
  year    ={2016},
  publisher={The Bad},
  address ={The Ugly}}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{majorbookch1} said something. I actually do not need to cite \citet{majorbook}

\bibliography{bib.bib}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\end{document}
```

In the bibliography-list this always appears as:

> The Good (2016a), Chapter One, in *Some Nice Title* The Good (2016*b*), pp. 1-10.
>
> The Good, ed. (2016b), *Some Nice Title*, The Bad, The Ugly

But it looks way better to have the book as 2016a, especially in the cases that an editor wrote several chapters in his book, and when others writing in the same book are referred to as well.

How can I make the list sorted the way I want? I already tried the solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190842/same-author-same-year-bibliography-order), but it does not work.

[Note that I am not unwilling to try and learn biblatex or other bibliography-packages/tools/ways/etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230626/change-the-lay-out-of-the-bibliography)

Comment: Very good example.

Comment: Jopie: There are answers to some of your questions. I think you should consider to give feedback or even accept them before piling up more questions ;-)

Comment: Is `\nocite{8}` in your code `\nocite{*}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default sorting scheme with `biblatex` is `nyt` (name, year, title). You can choose from a couple of predefined schemes, some more information can also be found in [biblatex sorting by date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46879/37907). In the following example, we use

```
booktitle             = {Korean cuisine},
sorttitle             = {Korean cuisineZ}
```

to get the cited chapter definitely behind the main book, which still isn't cited.

*enjoy your meal - 맛있게 드세요*

[image: jopieInbookSortScheme]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @inbook{majorbookch1,
        author                = {The ultimate Chief},
        title                 = {Bibimbap},
        pages                 = {1--10},
        crossref              = {majorbook},
        booktitle             = {Korean cuisine},
        sorttitle             = {Korean cuisineZ}
    }
@inbook{majorbookBulgogi,
    author                  = {Cook, Sun Lee},
    title                   = {Bulgogi},
    pages                   = {11-14},
    crossref                = {majorbook},
    booktitle               = {Korean cuisine}
}
    @book{majorbook,
        editor                = {The ultimate Chief},
        title                 = {Korean cuisine},
        subtitle              = {Tasty Korean Food},
        year                  = {2016},
        publisher             = {The Publisher},
        address               = {Behind the oven},
        sorttitle             = {Korean cuisine}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Bibimbap is tasty~\autocite{majorbookch1}, 
but so is \citetitle{majorbookBulgogi}~\autocite{majorbookBulgogi}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jopie Not sure if you get notified when an answer is updated.

Comment: If you star the question, I think you do.